# Accessing value of hidden variable in Javascript wiht VB

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I tried the following code but did not succeed.It would be great if you could guide me. I was trying to test using a simple "Hello". In the actual program I would assign a string value to the hidden field.

I get an Alert box ( using this to test whether the value is accessible in javascript ) but with no values.

**Server Side**

```
ivar.Value = "Hello"
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    function getval() {
        var v = document.getElementById('<%= ivar.ClientID%>').value;
        alert(v)
    }
</script>
```

**Form**

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="CALCULATE" onclientclick="getval()" />
<asp:HiddenField ClientIDMode="static" id="ivar" runat="server" Value=""/>
```

Comment: are you missing a semicolon (;) after your alert(v) ?

Comment: When you view the page source, so you see a value attribute on the hidden input? Does it have the value you expect? Does the serverside code get executed when you set a breakpoint on the line?

Comment: @miche : Thanks for reminding me but it still did not return me a value . It just shows an alert box that is empty

Comment: @epascarello: Yup. I can see 'Hello' in the value part on debugging.

Comment: considering you set ClientIDMode to static on that control you do not even need VB to access it. just use document.getElementById("ivar").value

Comment: @KHeaney : I tried by adding and removing the static property from the control but still for some reason I cannot get the value on the javascript side. While debugging I found that the value does get stored in the server side.

Comment: your code seems correct. the only thing I can think of is where precisely is your script block? is it on the aspx page? is it in a master page? is in in the head or body? The thought is you may be outside the variable scope for the vb version. no clue why the pure js one would not work though.

Comment: @KHeaney: The javascript function on the aspx page within the script tags and in the head. Guess I'll find a way somehow and post the answer here. Thanks a lot for your help and time,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us say you have a public variable on server side:

```
public string iVar = "Hello";
```

You can directly add it to your javascript as below:

```
<script>
    function getval() {
        var v = <%=iVar%>;
        alert(v);
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to find the client id in your script block may be trying to find the hidden field before it exists. try moving the script to the bottom of the page just before you close your body tag and see if that helps.

Comment: Just a wild thought. Would this be because I am assigning the value to the hidden field in a protected sub ?

Comment: should not be. you said it was in the hidden field when you hit f12 and inspected the page. once the variable is on the page how you set it does not come into play.

Comment: I just removed the entire hidden field and modified the code. Thanks a bunch for your help.